# Get path relative to %(ProjectDir) in C++ code

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I use Visual Studio 2015 and I need to hold path as string of some file which is stored in the same directory with .vcxproj file(or relative to that directory). The problem is that **Output Directory** configuration parameter may be changed so I can't use path relative to .exe. Also hardcoding the value is not an option. Is it possible to get path of .vcxproj file ?

**Edit:** Is it possible to automatically place necessary file(s) in the %(OutputDir) after build ?

Comment: You could pass it as a parameter to the executable when launching it from VS. For general use, I'd question whether that makes sense though, because in the end, you only run the executable without the VS project or even VS.

Comment: Pass as an argument is not an option too. The code will be built and deployed in other environments but there is a guarantee that they(both source codes and executable) will be in the same virtual disk.

Comment: Then, you can pass this path to the compiler during the builds. I think this very approach is flawed though and only applicable in rare corner cases.

Comment: If passing the path to the compiler (as e.g. a preprocessor macro) then the path will be hard-coded into the executable. If the path doesn't match the location of deployment (even if you include the source, why?) attempting to use the file will fail.